# What's this anime with kids jumping off a roof and then hovering over the ground?

Tags: identification-request

All I can remember is that there was a girl riding a scooter/bicycle and she witnesses kids jumping off a roof to see who can get closer to the ground and just before they hit the ground they stop and hover. I can't remember anything else; it was about 8-10 years ago.

Answer (score 4):

That sounds like the "Beyond" segment of the anthology [The Animatrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Animatrix).

> "Beyond" is written and directed by Kōji Morimoto. It follows a teenage girl, Yoko (Hedy Burress), looking for her cat Yuki. While asking around the neighborhood, indicatively somewhere in Japan, she meets some younger boys. One of them tells her Yuki is inside a "haunted house" and invites her to see it.
>
> The children have stumbled across an amalgamation of anomalies within an old, dilapidated building. They have learned to exploit this glitch in the Matrix for their own enjoyment, through several areas which seem to defy real-world physics: glass bottles reassemble after being shattered, rain falls from a sunny sky, broken lightbulbs flicker briefly (during which they seem intact), a door which opens into an endless dark void, shadows which do not align with their physical origins, and a dove's feather that rotates rapidly in place in mid-air. **There is a large open space in the middle of the run-down building where they take turns jumping off a high point and falling towards the ground, yet somehow stopping inches before impact.** This proves amusing and they do not seem to be bothered by the inherent strangeness of the place.

Here it is on YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tBJe53IA9DE